# Adding punctuation to US and European patent numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I want to add custom punctuations in a given string.

eg:

```
US 8012999 B2 --> US 8,012,999 B2
US 20170107206 A1 --> US 20170107206 A1
EP 2795605 B1 --> EP 2 795 605 B1
US 09700674 --> US 09/700,674
```

This is what I wrote

```
def punctuate(text, punctuations):
    """Given text and list of tuple(index, puncuation)
    returns punctuated text"""

    char_list = list(text)
    k = 0
    for i, char in punctuations:
        char_list.insert(i + k, char)
        k += 1
    return "".join(char_list)

In [53]: punctuate('US 8012999 B2', [(4, ','), (7, ',')])
Out[53]: 'US 8,012,999 B2'

In [54]: punctuate('US 20170107206 A1', [(7, '/')])
Out[54]: 'US 2017/0107206 A1'

In [55]: punctuate('US 09700674', [(5, '/'), (8, ',')])
Out[55]: 'US 09/700,674'

In [56]: punctuate('EP 2795605 B1', [(4, ' '), (7, ' ')])
Out[56]: 'EP 2 795 605 B1'
```

This works fine. Is this the best way to do it?
The punctuations list will always be sorted one starting from lower to higher index.

Comment: Yeah, always. For now. I also thought of sorting it first regardless but it will again unnecessarily complicate thing here by creating x,y problem.

Comment: What is the reason for this code? what is the business requirement? Why do you need to add punctuations like this?

Comment: These are the punctuations used by USPTO and EPO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using a generator, which gives you linear time. Your current solution is not linear, because `list.insert` is already \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

```
def interweave(x, y):
    """
    Given an iterable `x` and an iterable `y` of indices and items, 
    yield from `x`, but interweave the items from `y` at the given indices.
    """
    y = iter(y)
    next_i, next_y = next(y, (-1, ""))
    for i, next_x in enumerate(x):
        if i == next_i:
            yield next_y
            next_i, next_y = next(y, (-1, ""))  # default value for when y is exhausted
        yield next_x

def punctuate(text, punctuations):
    return "".join(interweave(text, punctuations))
```

It passes all the given testcases:

```
In [98]: punctuate('US 8012999 B2', [(4, ','), (7, ',')])
Out[98]: 'US 8,012,999 B2'

In [99]: punctuate('US 20170107206 A1', [(7, '/')])
Out[99]: 'US 2017/0107206 A1'

In [100]: punctuate('US 09700674', [(5, '/'), (8, ',')])
Out[100]: 'US 09/700,674'

In [101]: punctuate('EP 2795605 B1', [(4, ' '), (7, ' ')])
Out[101]: 'EP 2 795 605 B1'
```

Comment: Thanks. It took time for me to fully understand it. This is amazing and also fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the context of a task is needed to determine whether this is the best way. At least, you would do refactoring of the existing solution.

```
def punctuate(text, punctuations):
    if not punctuations:
        return text
    i, char = punctuations.pop()
    return punctuate(text[:i], punctuations) + char + text[i:]
```

Less code and better performance.

Comment: I actually can't easily guess what's going on while looking at recursive solution. I have to see it on pythontutor. This is excellent.

Comment: Welcome to CR numrut. Could you please specify why the recursive solution is better? I don't think mutating punctuations and recusing for this is a good idea.